# To avoid over-fitting an ensemble model, should one penalize at both the ensemble and the individual model levels?

Tags: multiple-regression, forecasting, regularization, overfitting, ensemble-learning

If you have an ensemble method that is similar to your lower-level modeling methods, such as a weighted average of a set of penalized linear models (LASSO, ridge, or whatever), with the weights chosen for best fit of the ensemble (perhaps also by regression), should one penalize the ensemble weights as well?

Conversely, if you have a set of forecasts from various forecasting models, and you treat them as the independent variables in a linear model and penalize that model, does that make it unnecessary to do penalization to avoid over-fitting at the individual model level?

Will penalizing the ensemble of penalized models over-penalize the final ensemble results?

note that I am not using ensemble in the machine learning sense, but rather in the more general model combination sense.

Comment: I do not think there is a standard answer for this.  I would say that if your CV scores drop with the regularization in your 'meta' model then you shouldn't penalize it.  Otherwise, regularization will most likely help per usual.

Comment: Thanks@Tylerr! That makes sense. Do you think there is any problem with using the same left-out data to shrink the ensemble as was used to penalize the individual estimating equations?